# WebAPI with Entity Framework and relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, edmx

We have a problem with performance when using WebAPI and Entity Framework when the entity has a relationship.  As an example, we pulled 23000 records without the relationship and it took 2.1 seconds.  With the relationship it took 2.7 seconds.

I have disabled LazyLoading and ProxyCreation on the context, so they are no longer a factor.  The JSON files produced are almost identical with the only difference being on each entity there is a null Related Entity.

Does anyone know why there is such an overhead when having a relationship specified in the EDMX even though we are not using it?

Comment: Most probably the overhead is caused by JSON.Net still trying to *"touch"* the navigation property. A good try might be to put `[JsonIgnore]` attribute over the property so JSON.Net will not even bother to check it.